# How to extend physical device Limit?

Tags: networking, vpn, gateway

My Situation:
I just moved into a dorm which only allows for 2 MAC-Addresses per user.
I would like to use more devices than that.
All I have access to is one ethernet wall connector presumably coming from their router/switch.

My proposed Solution:
Hook up a VPN Gateway to that ethernet port and connect all other devices to this Gateway or maybe a switch behind that.
I already have a VPN-service that I can use.

The Questions:
1. Will the VPN Gateway hide my other MAC-addresses so my landlord only sees the Gateway itself?
2. So far I only found business VPN Gateways/-Routers and -Firewalls are there any consumer Products I can use?
3. Do you suggest another Solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need VPN, just NAT. Any home gateway router / wireless router with an Ethernet WAN port would work. NAT makes all your private LAN's traffic look like it's coming from a single IP address and MAC address.

Comment: Can i hook up the dsl port of the router to the network? otherwise it wouldnt do anything other than a switch right?

Comment: @toni714 - You cannot use a DSL/Cable gateway in a case like this.  You need a router/wireless router to acomplish your task.

Comment: @toni74 I just updated my answer to be more specific, that the router would need an Ethernet WAN port. If you have a router whose only WAN port is a phone jack (indicating a built-in DSL modem) or a coax connector (indicating a built-in DOCSIS modem) it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a VPN Gateway, any home router that supports upstream (WAN) ethernet will do what you need.

You just need to set it up to work in NAT mode then you can attach as many devices as you want on the LAN side, this can be either wired (most "home" routers have 3-5 LAN ports) or via WiFi (most home routers have built in WiFi access points).